# Can I turn off showing matplotlib plt plots for an entire script?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that I have developed in jupyter that does computation and periodically generates plots. These plots are generated, saved to disk, and then shown with plt.show().

**I would like to turn off showing plots entirely (but not generating and saving them) at the top of the script by setting some plt parameter.**

This is spread throughout a few different functions in the computation script. Running it in jupyter is fine, since the plots neither pause computation nor accumulate as windows, but when running the script from shell, they are annoying.

I could turn every call of "plt.show()" into a branching statement to call "plt.clf()" instead based on a global variable, but that would require changing lots of bits of code and add unnecessary complexity. Thus,I hope that there is a neater and cleaner way to accomplish this.

Comment: What about setting a state variable somewhere and adding an if statement based on it?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. See the last paragraph of my post. That's a solution that would work, but I would find it a bit ugly and unnecessary to add branching around every call of plt.show(), so I am hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: So how do you expect the script to know? You want it to randomly show or not show when you call plt.show()?

Comment: "I would like to turn off showing plots entirely (but not generating and saving them) at the top of the script by setting some plt parameter." I was hoping that there might be some setting of matplotlib / plt that I could set that surpresses showing of plots. So while a flag needs to be set somewhere, I would like to add it only once, and not wrap every call of plt.show() in an if-else statement.

Comment: Good luck. If a state variable doesn't work for you, I'm out of options.

Comment: Maybe that is the best solution. Thanks for your help.